# Remove string from file name, using windows cmd

Tags: regex, batch-file, cmd

**EDIT:**
Thank you all, 
Magoo tips fix it , I using the following code:

```
echo off
cls
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for %%f in (*.mov) do (
    set name=%%~nf
    set new_name=!name:*_= !
    echo File renamed from: !name!.mov to:!new_name!.mov
    rename %%f !new_name!.mov
)
```

This only works if the file name is something_file_name.mov. If original file is only file_name.mov, I end up it only name.mov
So using REGEX is the best option.
I'm using a tweaked version of Ben Personick and Squashman suggestions.

```
@echo off
cls
SET "_Regex=^[0-9]*_"

FOR %%F IN (*.mov) DO (
    ECHO.%%~nF | findstr /R "%_Regex%" >nul && (
        FOR /F "Tokens=1* Delims=_" %%f IN ("%%~nxF") DO (
            MOVE /Y "%%F" "%%g"
        )
    )
)
```

I have some files named 3424_file_name.mov and need to remove the numbers until the first _ so to get file_name.mov 
Even better would be to set a range to remove like [0-9] 
Like to do it in cmd windows 7. This is what i got so far, but not working.

```
cls
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for %%f in (*.mov) do (
 set name=%%~nf
 set new_name=%name%:*_=x
 echo %new_name%)
 rename %%f %new_name%.mov
 )
```

Thanks
Alex

Comment: Please us e the search facility in the top bar to find out about `delayed expansion`  the #1 FAQ in this tag. Since you've invoked `delayed expansion`, you need to access the *changed* value of a variable using `!varname!` instead of `%varname%`

Comment: Also, your `set` command is incorrect. You need `set var1=!var2:*_=x!` (note the position of the `!`s)

Comment: You also have to remove the closing parenthesis in the echo line, that ends the scope of the for loop and the rename has no more a `%%f` var

Comment: You do not edit your question title to mark the question solved.  You chose one of the answers below by clicking on the check mark next to the answer.

Comment: I highly recommend starting to learn PowerShell. `cmd.exe` scripting is riddled with arcane syntax and odd quirks. PowerShell is consistent and more readable (see my answer).

Comment: Sir Ale,  Yes, you can for-go the inner loop if you want to run the script from the same location as the files to be renamed. Using the *_*.mov file glob will also further limit the initial results, making it faster than *.mov for each .mov file that has no underscore in its name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would do the needful.

Note how I am using MOVE /Y in case the file is read-only, as Rename cannot handle renaming Read-only files.

```
SETLOCAL
ECHO OFF

SET "_Regex=^[0-9][0-9]*_.*"
SET "_FileGlob=*_*.Mov"
SET "_FilePath=C:\Path"

FOR %%F IN ("%_FilePath%\%_FileGlob%") DO (
    ECHO.%%~nF | FINDSTR /R "%_Regex%" >NUL && (
        FOR /F "Tokens=1* Delims=_" %%f IN ("%%~nxF") DO (
            MOVE /Y "%%~F" "%%~dpF%%~g"
        )
    )
)
ENDLOCAL
```

Comment: That regular expression will not work with `FINDSTR`.

Comment: Tweaked the SET "_Regex=^^[0-9]+_.*"   to    SET "_Regex=^[0-9]_" and  removed %%dp from MOVE /Y "%%F" "%%dpF%%g".

Comment: What is the %%dp on MOVE /Y "%%F" "%%dpF%%g" do ?

Comment: @SirAleXbox, they are modifiers for the `FOR` variable.  They are explained at the end of the help file for the `FOR` command.

Comment: the Tildes "~" tell the for loop to expand the variable, stripping any double quotes off the ends, and splitting it into different portions based on which other modifiers you present. n = name, x=extention, d=drive, p=path, and so on and so forth.

Comment: I'm used to needing to double carets "^" when storing a caret, but I'm normally using them within calls, so it turned out not o be needed here.  The Paths are not necessary unless they are changing, so yess you can strip the %%~dpF, or keep it, both are OK.

Comment: There is no `+` meta-character for [`findstr`](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html), so the `[0-9]+` must be changed to `[0-9][0-9]*` to get what you want. And put `%_Regex%` in between `""` to keep the `^`-sign!

Comment: @aschipfl  yeah, I forgot that it's only *, the Regex is already enclosed in quotes, I'm often using FOR and CALL to expand which can strip carats in certain situations where I can't.  My comment was only that is the source of the earlier accidental double carat.  Seems like you down-voted it due to that..?

Comment: Yes, I did down-vote, because the former answer was wrong, but I retracted it meanwhile as you may have noticed...

Comment: @aschipfl Thanks for explaining the reason, and for the retraction :)  I make a habit to check back through and tweak old posts once in a while to make sure they're solid, but I didn't notice the downvote at the time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the underscore to your advantage if you use a `FOR /F` command instead.  This will allow you to break up the file name into two variables.

```
@echo off

for /F "tokens=1* delims=_" %%G in ('dir /a-d /b *.mov ^|findstr /RC:"^[0-9][0-9]*_"') do (
    rename "%%~G_%%~H" "%%~H"
)
```

Comment: That would also remove non numeric prefixes

Comment: @LotPings, good point.  I will change it to pipe it to findstr.

Comment: It may have been bettter to have filtered the `*.mov` files further, more especially because of the possibility of the renamed files being cycled back into the `dir` command!

Comment: What is the  ^ on dir /a-d /b *.mov ^  ? and why double [0-9] ?

Comment: The caret or circumflex is needed to escape the PIPE.  It is always needed when using a `FOR /F` command to capture output from another command.  The caret or circumflex in the `FINDSTR` command is used to match at the beginning.  That is clearly documented in the help for the `FINDSTR` command.

Comment: The two character classes is also easily explained.  The first one makes sure the file name starts with a number.  The second character class is followed by an asterisk.  So if you read the help file for the `FINDSTR` command, it says: **Repeat: zero or more occurrences of previous character or class**.  The `FINDSTR` command has very limited Regular Expression usage.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simpler task in PowerShell. Example:

```
Get-ChildItem *.mov | ForEach-Object {
  $fileName = $_.Name
  if ( $fileName -match '^[0-9]+_' ) {
    $newName = $fileName -replace '^[0-9]+_', ''
    Rename-Item $fileName $newName
  }
}
```

As other have commented, this can redesigned to be shorter and more efficient. Example:

```
Get-ChildItem *.mov |
  Where-Object { $_.Name -match '^\d+_' } |
  Rename-Item -NewName ($_.Name -replace '^\d+_','')
```

The purpose here is to illustrate how PowerShell is far more powerful and flexible than `cmd.exe` batch scripting.

Comment: I would think that `$name -match` would need to be `$_.Name -match`. Also, how about `Rename-Item $_.FullName $($_.Name -replace '^[0-9]+_', '')`

Comment: …and why not use `\d+`?

Comment: A where could replace the foreach and the if as rename-item accepts piped input. `ls [0-9]*_*.mov|?{$_.name -match '^[0-9]+_'}|ren -newname {$_.Name -replace '^[0-9]+_'}`

Comment: The original is essentially the same as the cmd method, tasking about the same number of lines and using the loops.  The second version you wrote as suggested by @LotPings is a much better leverage of the power of Powershell, where the true benefit often stems from the ability to avoid loops.

Comment: @BenPersonick Even simpler with a capture group in the match RE `gci *_*.mov|? Name -match '^\d+_(.*)$'|ren -newname {$Matches[1]} -whatif`

Comment: @LotPings, true, it's much better to pipe the match result in less hassle than setting up a replace.  And I appreciate the compactify as it's also a benefit of PS, in Bills there is unnecessary use of curlys and whatnot, however I do at advocate to giving example code that is not very compactified unless its a stated goal of the question, as people are looking to learn, and the longer form is more descriptive, not everyone knows GCI is get-childitem, it might cause someone looking to learn confusion.  But Absolutey is it tighter and nicer in a script.

Comment: @BenPersonick Agreed, in my own **answers** I usually also present the more verbose version `Get-ChildItem *_*.mov|Where-Object Name -match '^\d+_(.*)$'|Rename-Item -NewName {$Matches[1]} -WhatIf`