# Get file name including spaces from FOR loop

Tags: batch-file, cmd

**EDIT:** Here is my complete code.

```
@echo off
cls
Set "file=%~f1"
Set "f_name=%~n1"
Set "n_name=%f_name: =_%"
Set "target=C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop"
ffmpeg -i "%file%" ^
       -dn ^
       -an ^
       -r 25 ^
       -vcodec hap ^
       -format hap_alpha  ^
       "%target%\%n_name%_Hap_alpha_v1.mov"
pause
```

I'm using this code to execute something on a given file.
But if the file name includes spaces "file name Red_v3.mov" I only get "Red_v3.mov" as output on %%~nxF how to get the name including spaces?
So that I can replace " " with "_" using set %file_1% %f_name: =_%

```
@echo off
set file=%~dpnx1
for %%F in (%file%) do ( 
    Set f_ext=%%~nxF
    Set f_name=%%~nF
    )
echo %file% 
echo %f_ext%
echo %f_name%
pause
```

Thanks
Alex

Comment: Start getting in the habit of using quotes for everything.  It protects spaces and special characters.

Comment: You know that `%~dpnx1` is the same as `%~f1` ? Also double quote file names with spaces.

Comment: You were shown that in the answer to your previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49989297/1417694).

Comment: Felt really stupid now, thanks Dint realize %~dpnx1 and %~f1 also the "%file%" was under my nose.

Comment: Not understanding why you posted that additional code. You can't access the file if you change the space to an underscore.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. Should have given more info. Hope I fix it now I've added the complete code. Its a .bat linked to the contextual menu for media files. Allows me to copy form the network and convert at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you are not using quotes, but there is absolutely no need to set the command line argument to an environmental variable and then use a `FOR` command to split up the file name again.  You already can do that by using the command line argument.

```
@echo off
set "file=%~f1"
Set "f_ext=%~x1"
Set "f_name=%~n1"
```